# Rails - How Do I do this Query? Get One of Each Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a `BlogPost` model with a `:category` attribute.  I am making a new `BlogPost` form, and I would like for the select menu to populate itself with each category entered in previous records by the user.

Therefore, I need one query to find all `BlogPosts` with a `User ID`, and then round up a list of each category they have entered.  The same category will exist in multiple records, but of course I only want to return copy of it for the select menu.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `SELECT DISTINCT` categories returned an `INNER JOIN` to the right user :

```
Category
  .joins( :posts )
  .where( posts: { user_id: current_user.id } )
  .uniq
```

This should send a query like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT categories.*
FROM categories
  INNER JOIN posts ON posts.category_id = categories.id
WHERE posts.user_id = [whatever]
```

*EDIT NOTE:* be wary that `uniq` is both a method on a `Relation` and on an `Array`. Be sure to call it on the relation before it is cast to an array, or you will perform the uniq on an array of non-distinct results, which works too, but is absurd performance-wise.

Comment: Trim the second `JOIN` to users, it's not needed.